# Why i cannot delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I hope anyone cal help me solve this one. I  really answer for this particular problem because i have to complete this task for my course presentation... i really need all your help....pleasee... im begging...

I've created this page(delete.php) for search details to delete

```
<?php require('sambung.php');  ?>
 action="delete2.php" method="post"> <table><tr><td>Carian Nama untuk
 Penternak:</td> <td><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" /></td>
 <td><br> type="submit" name="submit" value="Hantar"/></td></tr>
 </table>




 </Form>

 </body></head></html>
```

then it will send through this page which name is delete2.php

> IDNama  Status
>
> $submit = $_POST["submit"];
>
> if($submit=="Hantar") {
>       if(isset($_POST["nama"]))
>       {        // create the query
>                  $nama = $_POST["nama"];
>
> ```
>            $sql = "SELECT * FROM penternak WHERE nama LIKE '%$nama%' ";
>             // execute query
>             $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL select statement failed");
>             // retrieves a row data and returns it as an associative array
>            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>            // display direct from array
>
>
>          echo "<tr>";
>          echo "<td>$row[id] <br></td>";
>         ?>
>          <td><?php echo "$row[nama]"; ?> </td>
>          <td> 
>            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
>
>            </a><br></td>
>           <?php
>
>          }
>          print "</table>\n";
>
>               } 
>
>   }     
>    ?>       </table> </form> </body> </html>
> ```

then when i click delete button, i will send to this page name deletepenternak.php...but when i checked back, it doesnt delete anything from database...

```
> <?php require('sambung.php');  ?>
> 
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head>
> 
> <body>
> 
> <?php
> 
> 
> $submit= $_POST['submit'];
> 
> if ($submit='submit') {       if (isset($_POST["id"]))    {
>       $id=$_POST["id"];        $sql = "DELETE * FROM penternak WHERE id='$id'
> ";
>                 // execute query
>                 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL select statement failed");    echo "<h3>Maklumat telah dihapuskan...</h2><br>";
>   echo "<a href='viewpenternak.php'>[View current records]</a>";      } }
> ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Nice code `S-T-I-T-C-H` ;-) Do properly format your question/code.

Comment: thx...i dont know how to use this...this is my first time using this forum..btw its very cool..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to delete something with id `delete`, since that's the value of your element (the submit button). You will need to add the id. This should work:

Instead of your current delete button, use this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="Delete">
```

Then, in your postback:

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if (!empty($submit))
{
    $idToDelete = key($submit);
    // your query here
}
```

Comment: thank...i already done that...and now it said "SQL select statement failed"...can you interprate that...? sorry for disturbing.. and my sql is " $sql = "DELETE * FROM penternak WHERE id='$idToDelete' ";
                // execute query
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL select statement failed");" is that right?

Comment: Replace `or die("SQL select statement failed");` with `die("SQL select statement failed: ".mysql_error())`;
What does it say?

Comment: SQL select statement failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM penternak WHERE id='1003'' at line 1

Comment: Ah, the correct syntax for a delete query is `DELETE FROM`, you have `DELETE * FROM`. Remove the `*` from your query and you should be good.

Comment: hey..it work...first of all, thank you so much...and really glad about that..and now i have to think about update that cannot running in database.. o.o'

Answer (score 0):

It's not `DELETE * FROM table where x=y` it's `DELETE FROM table where x=y` .. No * is required.

Comment: thanks...when i do some research..i dont know where the hell * is come from... -.-'